# PHP input into mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, row

I'm trying to put the input form in my database but it won't work.  Here is my code:

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="removed"; // Mysql username 
$password="removed"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="removed"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="input"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form 
$email=$_POST['email'];

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(email) VALUES('$email')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='insert.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

hi

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="./php/email2db.php">
<input type="text" name="email" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Pass The Popcorn</button>
</form>
```

Can you help me get it so when they out it in it goes on the database? I want it to and it's not so please help.

Comment: "it wont work" what specifically happens?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Also, change `"$host", "$username", "$password"` to `$host, $username, $password`

Comment: it says ERROR when i try it

Comment: Don't tell us there's an error message. Tell us WHAT the error message says. Then we can google the error message and find out what causes it (or know if we've experienced it personally)

Comment: I did, I said it says ERROR

Comment: @ChrisChapman That's not an error message. Instead of echoing "ERROR", echo `mysql_error()` and tell us what the error is. And for the love of peace *please* stop using `mysql_*` functions and use PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query should look like this:

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="removed"; // Mysql username 
$password="removed"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="removed"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="input"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
//Removed the " from $db_name, $host, $username, $password

// Get values from form 
$email=$_POST['email'];

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO ".$tbl_name." (email) VALUES(".$email.")";
//Here you have to concatenate the query from multiple parts, this is important
//And you cant use "$tbl_name(email)"
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='insert.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your Code Should be

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 

$username="removed"; // Mysql username 
$password="removed"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="removed"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="input"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
$conn   =   mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($db_name,$conn)or die("cannot select DB");
//Removed the " from $db_name, $host, $username, $password
// Get values from form 
$email=$_POST['email'];
// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO `".$tbl_name."` (`email`) VALUES('".$email."')";
//Here you have to concatenate the query from multiple parts, this is important
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result)
{
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<a href='insert.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else 
{
    echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `INSERT INTO $tbl_name(email) VALUES('$email')` you are basically saying that the name of your table is $tbl_name(email) as-is which is not the case. You need to rewrite the sql as INSERT INTO ".$tbl_name." (email) VALUES(".$email.")